# Labels FacetGrid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data like this.

```
big_category category variable value
a aa111111111 x 1.2
a ba111111111 x 1.05
a ca111111111 x 1.11
a aa111111111 y 1.43
a ba111111111 y 1.09
a ca111111111 y 0.97
a aa111111111 z 1.12
a ba111111111 z 1.46
a ca111111111 z 1.32
b ab111111111 x 1.2
b ab111111111 y 1.05
b ab111111111 z 1.11
c ac111111111 x 1.2
c bc111111111 x 1.05
c cc111111111 x 1.11
c ac111111111 y 1.43
c bc111111111 y 1.09
c cc111111111 y 0.97
c ac111111111 z 1.12
c bc111111111 z 1.46
c cc111111111 z 1.32
```

Code:

```
big_theme <- theme(
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black", colour = NA),
plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 15, color = "white"),
axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "white", size = 14),
axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white", size = 14),
axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "white", size = 14),
axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 1, angle = 45, color = "white", size = 14, hjust=1),
strip.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
strip.text = element_text(colour = 'white'),
strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0),
legend.position = "top"
)

theme2 = theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
legend.background=element_rect(fill = "black"),
legend.text = element_text(colour = "white", size = 14),
legend.justification = "right",
legend.key.height = unit(1, "line"),
legend.key = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "black"))

theme3 = theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'))

ggplot(sample_data %>% mutate(variable=fct_relevel(variable, c("z","x","y")))) +
geom_col(position = "identity",
aes(x = category, y = value, fill = variable, color = variable)) +
facet_grid(. ~ big_category, space="free_x", scales="free_x", switch="x") +
big_theme + theme2 + theme3 +
theme(strip.placement = "outside",
strip.background = element_rect(fill=NA,colour="white"),
panel.spacing.x=unit(0,"cm"),
strip.text = element_text(hjust=0, face="bold", size=12))
```

Graphic

[image]
I want the x-axis to be labeled by category and below that I want labels for big_category. I have already done this, but there are couple things I'm not able to change. I want the big category label to go all the way to the bottom left of the label. Right now it goes to the left of the chart but not the label. Also, I want to be able to remove the big_category label for big_categories with less than 2 categories.